# Microsft Edge wont execute script.onload

Tags: javascript, typescript, microsoft-edge

I'm loading dynamic javascript libraries and I want to do something after they are loaded. Using typescript + angular 8
ie.

```js
const onLoaded = () => console.log('loaded')

const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://somesite.com/my-lib.js';
script.type="text/javascript";
script.onload = onLoaded;
head.appendChild(script);
```

The `onload` *Event* works as expected in *Chrome* and *Firefox*.. and what a surprise, it doesn't in *MS Edge*.
I tried loading using jQuery*, adding `addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false)` adding `onreadystatechange` ... Nothing.
Anybody had similar issues? Anybody know how to fix this? 
I need to add support for at least `Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363`

Comment: Works ok for me here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/Lbchn5p1/. Edge 44.18362.449.0

Comment: wow. You're right. Something in my code then. Thank you

Comment: How you implemented the onload?

Comment: If you change to typescript it stops working.. Forgot to mention I'm on typescript (angular 8)

Comment: Did you see any error in the Edge browser? Do you have the same exact script in your ts file that you had posted in the post? What happened when you load the page in the Edge browser?

Comment: I think it's the library I am trying to load that is failing. I don't get any errors on edge, and I tried loading a different library and it works perfectly. I need to look for the real problem. Thank you eveyone.

Comment: Thanks for informing us that another library is working fine so it can be related to that specific library that is not working. If possible then can you share some information about that library or the detailed steps for reproducing the issue? We can try to make a test to check for the issue.

Comment: It's actually that Edge is not loading the external library correctly. I clean cache and it stills read from cache (don't know what cache because it was emptied). And only on localhost environment. It is working in production, staging, test environments.

Comment: As it is working with other libraries, If possible for you then can you please provide any sample or reference for the library that can help to reproduce the issue on our end? We will try to make a test to check for the issue with the MS Edge legacy browser.